# Get Facebook public posts from a page to a php array

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I just need a code sample that collects public posts from a facebook page to a PHP array.

I've created an APP so I have the App ID/API Key and App Secret.

For example, let's say that I want to get all the stackoverflow public posts from Facebook. I've found out that stackoverflow's facebook page id is '11239244970', but now, how do I get all their public posts?

```
$appKey = '635000000000874';
$appSecret = '567xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3e6';
$fbPage = '11239244970';
$publicFeed = array();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You execute an HTTP GET to PAGE_ID/feed

`HTTP GET https://graph.facebook.com/11239244970/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#feed

in PHP it can be as basic as

```
$data  = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/573948779291487/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

or you can use the PHP SDK.

```
$publicFeed = $facebook->api('/573948779291487/feed');
```

To get only the page's own posts and not the fans who like the page, use the `/posts` endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Can I somehow filer out all other posts on the feed? I just want to get the posts from stackoverflow and not from their followers.

Comment: @budidino replace `/feed` with `/posts`

Comment: The id used - 11239244970, is the page id. Please tell me how to get that if we know a page url?

Comment: To get profile or page ID, go to https://findmyfbid.com and copy & paste the page's URL